# every open interval contains a rational number?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have recently started reading this book called "*A Course in Probability Theory*" by Kai Lai Chung. In the very first chapter of the book, he proves the following assertion for an increasing function $f(.)$

> The set of discontinuities of $f$ is countable.

In the proof, he considers for each point of jump $x$, the interval $I_x = (f(x-), f(x+))$ where $f(x-)$ and $f(x+)$ are the left and right hand limits of $f$ at $x$ respectively. Later in the proof he says that each such interval contains a rational number.

Now, this may be very obvious and simple, but I am not very much fluent with topology and I am not being able to see how this is true. Is this because the set of rational numbers is (everywhere) dense in $(-\infty, +\infty)$?

Further then, he uses this fact to reason that the collection of pairwise disjoint open intervals such as $I_x$ described above is countable. Then, can we similarly reason that any collection of pairwise disjoint open intervals on $R$
 will always be countable?

Comment: It is precisely because the rationals are dense in $R$. In fact, one way to characterize density is for the rationals to have a nonempty intersection with every open set; hence, every open interval. This leads to a natural proof of your second question.

Comment: Thank you @DavidKraemer. How can I show that the rationals have a non-empty intersection with every open interval on $R$?

Comment: take an open interval of length $l>0$, Take positive integer $n$ big enough so that $\frac1n<l$. One of the numbers $\frac mn$, $m\in\Bbb Z$ must belong to the open interval.

Comment: @Mirko .... & the existence of some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $1/n<l$  comes from the definition of $\Bbb R$....We can extend $\Bbb R$ to a larger ordered field  where this does not hold for every $l>0.$ So we MUST use the definition of $\Bbb R$ to prove this.

Comment: I suggest you study the logical basis of $\Bbb R,$ which, interestingly, was not explicitly developed until the latter 19th century.